# ASP.Net MVC: How to iterate in authorize or restricted controllers and actions name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to get controllers and protected action name and populate my class with controller and action name.

### see the below code

```
[Authorize]
public class Test1Controller : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index1()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index2()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index3()
    {
        return View();
    }   
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public class Test2Controller : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index1()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index2()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index3()
    {
        return View();
    }   
}

public class Test3Controller : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index1()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index2()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index3()
    {
        return View();
    }   
}
```

1) **Test1Controller** is protected but Index3 action has Anonymous access. so i want to iterate in such a way as a result i will get Test1Controller name and two its action name which has no allow Anonymous attribute.

2) **Test2Controller** has Anonymous attribute but two of its action is protected. so i want to get Test2Controller name and two of its action name.

3) **Test3Controller** has no protection for any of its action so this controller name and any of its action name will not come when i will iterate in controller and action collection.

the below code give me all controller and action name which is not my requirement

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

var controlleractionlists = asm.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => typeof(System.Web.Mvc.Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public))
            .Where(m => !m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true).Any())
            .Select(x => new { Controller = x.DeclaringType.Name.Replace("Controller",string.Empty), Action = x.Name, ReturnType = x.ReturnType.Name, Attributes = String.Join(",", x.GetCustomAttributes().Select(a => a.GetType().Name.Replace("Attribute", ""))) })
            .OrderBy(x => x.Controller).ThenBy(x => x.Action).ToList();
```

so please tell me what kind of change i need to incorporate in above code as a result those controllers name i will get which has at least one protected action.

please help me with rectified code. thanks

Comment: Test2Controller has no protected actions. AllowAnonymous ignores the nested Authorize attributes.

Comment: Your Where must be like this: .Where(m=>m.GetCustomAttributes<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any())

Comment: You can also use a filter to set Authorize by default on all controllers. How are you going to detect that?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg test2controller has AllowAnonymous  attribute but it has tow action with authorize attribute.

Comment: Try it for yourself. You can access both methods without having to login.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg can i use location tag in web.config file to protect those two action.....then AllowAnonymous ignores the nested Authorize attributes ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You can overcome this issue by setting the attributes like in Test1Controller.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg thanks for your advise.

Comment: I do not understand the requirement. Can you explain what your goal is, without thinking in solutions?

Comment: i would design a UI where only those controller and action name will be show which has at least one protected action and there i will associate role with all protected action and later assign role to that user. all the info will be saved in db. so when a user try to access any action then i want to check user has any access to that action or not by a custom attribute driven validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//for actions with AuthorizeAttribute
var actions = asm.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => typeof(System.Web.Mvc.Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public))
            .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute), true).Any())
            .Select(x => new { Controller = x.DeclaringType.Name.Replace("Controller", string.Empty), Action = x.Name, ReturnType = x.ReturnType.Name, Attributes = String.Join(",", x.GetCustomAttributes().Select(a => a.GetType().Name.Replace("Attribute", ""))) })
            .OrderBy(x => x.Controller).ThenBy(x => x.Action);

//for controllers with AuthorizeAttribute
var controllers = asm.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => typeof(System.Web.Mvc.Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .Select(type => type.GetTypeInfo())
            .Where(type => type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute), true).Any())
            .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public))
            .Where(m => !m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymousAttribute), false).Any())
            .Select(x => new { Controller = x.DeclaringType.Name.Replace("Controller", string.Empty), Action = x.Name, ReturnType = x.ReturnType.Name, Attributes = String.Join(",", x.GetCustomAttributes().Select(a => a.GetType().Name.Replace("Attribute", ""))) })
            .OrderBy(x => x.Controller).ThenBy(x => x.Action);

var controlleractionlists = actions.Concat(controllers).ToList();
```

If `AuthorizeAttribute` is set for action and controller level, this action will be in result twice but it can be fixed easly.

Comment: sure i will check your code and let you know how it works.

Comment: you have done this with 2 steps. one for controller and one for actions. so can't we do it in one place instead of 2 times separately?